# SolrPing.Process: Checked exception is invalid for this method

Tags: java, solr, junit, mockito, solrj

I am testing the exception condition for solr ping call. Here is the code snippet. **Solrj version 5.2.0**

```
@Test
public void testPingSolrWhenServerDown2() throws Exception {
  pingSolr = new PingSolr();
  SolrClient mockedSolrClient = Mockito.mock(SolrClient.class);
  SolrPing mockedSolrPing = Mockito.mock(SolrPing.class);
  PowerMockito.whenNew(SolrPing.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockedSolrPing);
  Mockito.doThrow(new IOException()).when(mockedSolrPing).process(mockedSolrClient);
  pingSolr.ping(mockedSolrClient);
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: java.io.IOException
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.SolrPing.createResponse(SolrPing.java:36)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:134)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:152)
    at c.i.j.s.i.PingSolrTest.testPingSolrWhenServerDown2(PingSolrTest.java:65)
```

This is saying `IOException` is an invalid checked exception, which is not allowed with mockito. The same is happening for `SolrServerException` in another test case.

But `SolrPing.process` method (extended from `SolrRequest`) does throw the exception. [SolrRequest.process](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrRequest.html#process%28org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient%29).

One thing I did observe that [`createResponse`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrRequest.html#createResponse%28org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient%29) does not throw any exception. But **When I am mocking the `process` call itself, why it is going to the further deeper calls**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are trying to mock

```
public final T process(SolrClient client, String collection)
```

is marked `final` which cannot be mocked by `Mockito`. Use `PowerMockito` instead, to mock methods that are `static` or `final`.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider to change the approach. I would move method call to `Solr` into protected method and with `spy` stub it as you need.

Sure it is less strong than `PowerMock` real interaction mocking as well it require to create a dummy method that is package visible.

But it was necessary for us since we had conflict with other test framework and it became habit that I accept and like since I don't need `PowerMock` anymore